# Maximum of K3 disjoint subgraphs of graph

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-theory

I am trying to solve a following problem: We have some graph. How to find (only number) maximum of K3 complete graphs which are subgraphs of input graph and are disjoint to each other.

I DO NOT need a code, a complete solution. I need an advice where to start. I thought about DFU and some traversing but it doesn't give a solution, at least not with some good time complexity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By disjoint I presume you mean any two triangles do not even share a vertex.

This is going to be NP-Hard.

[Partition into triangles](http://users.dimi.uniud.it/~romeo.rizzi/classes/Complexity/provette/Mirko/pt_fine.pdf) is NP-Complete, and can be reduced to your problem.

By constructing a graph of the triangles: each triangle is a vertex and two triangles are adjacent if they share a node. You could reduce it to the largest independent set problem, which probably has a lot of literature on algorithms/approximation algorithms etc.